# How to install the latest version of Pixel offline

Tags: image, pixel

I've been trying to find the latest pixel image on this [webpage](http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/images/). But I don't know which release is the latest pixel image. Can someone tell me which one is the one?
I have no internet connection on my pi so I cannot run `sudo apt-get update`and `sudo apt-get dist upgrade`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That web page is looking at the versions of Raspbian. [Pixel is a desktop environment](https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/introducing-pixel/). Recently Raspbian [Stretch](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspbian-stretch/) was released and can be seen on the page you referenced by the [latest folder date](http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/images/raspbian-2017-09-08/) (2017-09-08). So you would be able to get Pixel (the desktop environment for Raspberry Pi) on Stretch or on later versions of Jessie.

According to the [Raspberry Pi web site](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/introducing-pixel/), all you need to do yo update the version of Pixel is run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo reboot
```

And you will get the latest version of Pixel. You don't download it separately from Raspbian (Stretch, Jessie or otherwise)

More on this can be found on the [Wikipedia entry for Raspbian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspbian).

**EDIT**

Since the question has been edited to clarify that the Pi has no internet connection, I will edit this answer. To install components offline you need to find the .deb and transfer it to

> /var/cache/apt/archives/partial

on the Pi, and run

```
sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/***
```

where *** is the name of the deb file, as mentioned in [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/8335/42456)

Since there are thousands of deb packages, you'll have to find the required ones for pixel in some of these lists:

- http://www.raspberryconnect.com/raspbian-packages-list
- https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages
- http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/

Comment: I don't have internet connection on my pi. How am my supposed to run the update and all? Should I just download it separately using the web site I posted?

Comment: I have edited my answer in response to the editing of your question. Leaving out that offline bit was rather important!

Comment: Do you know which one is the required ones for pixel because I do not know which to find.

Comment: I really tried looking for you, could you at least give me an up vote for trying here and I'll dig a little deeper? Also - why can't you connect the pi to the internet?

Comment: I don't have an adapter.

Comment: And I don't have enough reputations to vote you up. Sorry:(

Comment: I'll still try - please do let me know why you can't connect the pi to the internet

Comment: I do not have an adapter.

Comment: So it's a Pi 0 or a Pi 0 W? You can't connect via Wifi?

Comment: pi 2. I need to buy an wifi adapter.

Comment: Ok... now if I may ask: how did you install Raspbian? Is Pixel currently running?

Comment: My friend gave the pi to me. I don't know what it is running on. How to know?

Comment: Ok so what I recommend is you follow the instructions here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/noobs-setup/2/ and download from here: https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/NOOBS_latest
You'll have everything up to date when you plug the SD card in.

Comment: I can't use raspbian?

Comment: Noobs stands for "New Out Of the Box" and it's just the installer for Raspbian, to make it easy for people like us :)

Comment: So this NOOBS gives me raspbian pixel?

Comment: No, it'll give you Raspbian Stretch with a Pixel desktop environment